# Budgie Black Wallpaper

Tags: fedora, wallpaper, budgie

I installed Budgie Desktop on Fedora Server 39.

The Problem is, that I also created a new Folder in the `/usr/share/backgrounds` directory, so that every user has access to it.
 First it was not showing up in Budgie Control Center, then I found out that you have to create a XML file `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties` wich I did using a Template from the Gnome Wiki and changing the Filepath to the correct image.
But Budgie Control center only shows a white preview of the Image and applying it results in a black Background.
Changing the Picture URI via GSettings seems to have the same effect